# Azure Maps Resize + Javascript won't get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-maps

I have built a Asp.net MVC view where I have map from Azure maps. I also have a sidebar which I can colapse to become smaller.

The code for collapsing the bar is the following (and is included in the _layout file):

```
 function collapse2() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    $('#content').toggleClass('active');

}
window.onload = function () {

    $("#sidebarCollapse").on('click', collapse2);
 }
```

In the view I have added the following javascript.

```
  function resize() {
                    map.map.resize();
                }
     $(document).ready(function () {



    GetMap();
    $(document).click('#resizea', resize);
     $(document).click('#sidebarCollapse', resize);
 });
```

When I press the  that has the ID of *sidebarCollapse* the sidebar collapses but the map don't resize ( it is not streching the 100 %). But if I click on the link  tag with id *resizea* after the collapse the map resizes tho the correct size.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks in advace!

Comment: I suspect that when you are calling the resize function on the map, the div the map is in hasn't resized yet. This would explain your issue. Also, try map.resize() instead of map.map.resize(). Not 100% sure why you have map.map, but there is a hidden feature in the map control that ties into the rendering engine and it also has a resize function, but I don't believe it will do what you need.

Comment: I think that you are on the right path. Is there a way to know that the div has resized or wait until it has?

I used map.map.resize() becuase of this:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d557e910-11d4-47bb-bd23-24fcf205b36e/azure-mapresize?forum=azurelbs

I tested both map,map.resize  and map.resize both seems to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I suspect the div hasn't resized yet. HTML doesn't provide any events for when a DOM element resizes other than the window. To know if something resizes you have to monitor it which is a pain to do yourself. Since you are using jquery you can use the resize function: https://api.jquery.com/resize/ It works with divs.

If that doesn't work. It sounds like the issue is when you press the sidebarCollapse button. I assume this button also collapses the sidebar, perhaps with a separate click event. Try combining them together and calling the resize function after the code for collapsing the sidebar is called. If you have an animation on the collapse, this may not work, in that case, wrap the resize function with setTimeout and use a time span that is slightly longer than the animation.